# Page not found 404 Django The current path , didn’t match

Tags: python-3.x, django, custom-error-pages

I tried to run Django for the first time and got this

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/new
Using the URLconf defined in test.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

hello/ [name='index']
hello/ [name='new']
admin/

The current path, hello/new, didn’t match any of these.

hello/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello, 1")

def new(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello, 2")
```

hello/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.new, name='new')
]
```

urls.py in my project directory

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', include('hello.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined a path matching your request, append "new" to one of the paths in your apps url config. Your paths should be unique anyway

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('new/', views.new, name='new')
]
```